# SlickGrid how to display 50lines

Tags: javascript, slickgrid

In my website i got a slickGrid to display a list of people with a rank. I want to implement automatic filter that display : 
 - First 50 guys/
 - Last 50 guys/
 - All

To do that i have try 1 thing :
I have a custom filter with one try the rank of a guy and if it's under 50 i display him. But the problem with this solution it's if i have more than one guy with the same rank, there is a possibility that my slickgrid display more than 50 lines.

With this method i have an other truble because i can't filter the 50 lasts guys, because i don't know the last rank and the number of people in my slickGrid.

My slickgrid is alreay sorted by rank so i'm wondering if there is a easy solution so said to my slickgrid display the first 50 lines / the last 50 lines or all the lines.

Thanks if you have a solution to my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all my suggestion is to use a defaultSort option:

```
$scope.usersGrid = {};
$scope.usersGrid.gridOptions = {
                defaultSort: {
                 id: 'loginName',
                 field: 'loginName',
                 asc: true
                 }
            };
```

Then while setting the rows you should maintain a javascript object:

```
$scope.usersGrid.setRows(users);
```

while using a an javascript object, which in our case is users, you can easily maintain a max length of 50 users.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but the thing that i want is different, because my server return me all the users so i had them only once and i don't know how many users i had in my slickgrid. do you understand my point ?

Comment: you can easily create a javascript array/list with maxlength of 50, sort the object, and then use slickGrid API to setRows. its much more recommended to maintain a javascript object instead of adding complex code to your slickGrid, please let me know if my answer is clear.

Comment: Thank you very much for this hint. I now use a javascript array and use a boolean to know if i want to display this object. That solution work very well. I upvote your solution !